# /lib/modules/2.6.38-8-generic/build: No such file or directory

Tags: 11.10, devices

I have ubuntu 11.10 installed on my system, upgraded from 11.04. 
I need to install the elok touch screen driver. as this driver only supports kernel 2.6 and not 3, I switched to kernel 2.6 in boot loader. now that I want to make the elok.so module, it gives me an error

```
make
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.38-8-generic/build SUBDIRS=/etc/opt/elo-ser/elok_s-source modules 
make: *** /lib/modules/2.6.38-8-generic/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

this error is becuase, when I upgraded from kernel 2.6 to kernel 3.0, kernel 2.6 was removed from /usr/src and in the /lib/modules/2.6.x.x there is no build directory.

I do not know how to solve this problem, please note the details of everything i should do to run my module.

Answer (score 17):

you have to download the linux headers and and build a system link

```
apt-get install linux-headers 
ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.38/ /lib/modules/2.6.38/build
```

Comment: Might need: sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)     This added the build link for me in Debian Jessie.